# package updates after changing code

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, synaptics-touchpad

I'm running Arch Linux.
So, what I did was I wanted to change the behavior of the synaptics driver, so I edited the code, complied to a package and then installed the package.
Then, the new update for synaptics comes along, and I upgrade.
The weird thing is that the behavior that I changed stayed the same.
So, I uninstalled, and then reinstalled the newest version, and it even give the version number as the newest version.
So either for some bizarre reason, it is keeping my changes, or synaptics actually made the same change I did.

Btw, the change I made was disabling movement of the cursor with three fingers. It originally allowed the cursor to move when you used 1 or 3 fingers, but I made it so it only moves when there is 1 finger.

Could someone confirm whether or not the new version has this change or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that synaptiks, in the newest version, does not move the cursor when there are three fingers on the touchpad, only when there is one finger on the touchpad. Two fingers can be used to scroll. You can make use of a three fingered tap.
I checked the [synaptiks changelog](http://synaptiks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changes.html), however, and I couldn't find any mention of this change.